# how to align comments in Android Studio to 'else' statement

Tags: android-studio, editor

I'm a little OCD when it comes to comments, so I really would like to have a comment above the 'else' statement (this is not production code, just for my own, so don't yell at me :-)

I do like the fact that Android Studio intelligently adjusts the code it inserts to the level of nesting, but I can't understand why it insists on having the comment one level deeper for the else statement, I guess I can't have the best of both worlds, but maybe there is a trick I don't know ... or maybe I'm the only one weird enough to care ...

```
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //---   bla bla bla
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------

            } else {
```

Comment: awesome, works like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because android-studio think that comment is part of your "if", you can handle it by selecting your comment, and use Shift+Tab in keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Press:

```
Ctrl + Alt + L (Windows)

Option + Command + L (Mac)
```

To align your code.

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything for me, the <SHIFT>-<TAB> seems to work though